# How to connect to Mosquitto MQTT Broker, that is running on a Google Cloud Virtual Machine Instance, using mqtt.js

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mosquitto, mqtt.js

**What I am trying to achieve:** I have a Mosquitto MQTT Broker running on a Google Cloud virtual machine (Ubuntu), and I want to be able to connect to it from my local PC using mqtt.js

**My setup**

I have created a VM instance in Google Cloud, running Ubuntu 20.04.LTS.

Some of the settings:

```
Firewall – allow HTTPS and allow HTTP
Firewall rule – opens port 1883
```

I installed Mosquitto MQTT Broker (version 1.6.9) on this VM.

I was able to verify the installation and that it was running, by opening to SSH terminals, one to publish, one to subscribe

```
mosquitto_sub -t test
mosquitto_pub -t test -m “hello”
```

Then I read that when I want to connect to VMs using third-party tools, I must create and upload my  own SSH keys to VMs:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f C:\keys\VM_KEYFILE -b 2048 pwd: ****
```

I got two files now, the private and public keys:

```
VM_KEYFILE
VM_KEYFILE.pub
```

I then used icacls to modify the private key’s permissions:

```
icacls.exe VM_KEYFILE /reset
icacls.exe VM_KEYFILE /grant:r “$($env:username):(r)”
icacls.exe VM_KEYFILE /inheritance:r
```

I then successfully connected ot the VM from a Windows console:

```
ssh -i "VM_KEYFILE" username@vm_public_ip_address
```

So now I want to try and connect using node.js

I already have a javascript file that uses mqtt.js to connect to some of the public MQTT brokers, e.g. HiveMQ
Some of its settings are:

```
let broker_host = 'broker.hivemq.com';
let broker_port = 1883;
let client_id = 'my_client_1';

const connection_options = {
    port: broker_port,
    host: broker_host,
    clientId: client_id,
    clean: true,
    keepalive: false
};
```

**My question:** How would I modify this JavaScript file to connect to the MQTT broker that is running in the Google Cloud VM

There is no username/password/authentication set up for the broker itself, just the VM.

I tried something like this, but I have no idea how to use the SSH key

```
let broker_host_gcm_vm = 'https://<vm_public_ip_address>
```

**UPDATE**

I can connect to the broker from both (a) MQTT Explorer, and (b) MQTTX deskptop app.

All I have to enter for the connection details is:

```
Host: mqtt://<ip address>
Port: 1883
```

Then I can publish / subscribe successfully.

I tried changing my JavaScript connection to the following, but I still can't connect from here:

```
let broker_host_gcm_vm1 = 'mqtt://<ip address>';
```

Comment: 1.6.9 is ancient. Is there a reason why you're not using the current version of Mosquitto? You're much more likely to get help with that.

Comment: It's what I got when I installed from within the Ubuntu (sudo apt-get install mosquitto)

Comment: I added an update to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

Let's say the host IP address is 11.22.33.44

The host was none of these:

```
let broker_host = 'http://11.22.33.44';
let broker_host = 'https://11.22.33.44';
let broker_host = 'mqqt://11.22.33.44';
let broker_host = 'mqtts://11.22.33.44';
```

But was simply this:

```
let broker_host = '11.22.33.44';
```

Simple when you know how :)